# Bit of the document separated by horizontal lines

Tags: numbering, line-spacing

Here's an example of what I want to do:

[image: ex]

I was wondering how does one separate a bit of text with horisontal lines neatly like that (keeping the numeration would be nice too)? Article environment is used here, I believe.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you seen the packages [`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) and [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)? I believe that the screenshot you show was made using one of them. If you don't manage to use them to fit exactly your needs, you can edit the question and ask about a more specific problem if you find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a tabular environment of some kind with the horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package. How to match the formatting of the rest of the example, apart from the lines, should be a separate question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}      % provides \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
 \toprule
Sator arepo tenet opera rotas\\
 \midrule
\lipsum[1]\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\vspace{2mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
```

Which will give you a horizontal line with a 2mm whitespace above and below. If you would like a more specific answer, consider asking a more specific question with an MWE.